# VS Code c++ IntelliSense exclude files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Currently using C++20, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseMemoryLimit": 8192`.

I have two folders `src` and `lib` in my project. I've got the C/C++ extension by Microsoft installed, and have set `C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine` to `Tag Parser` mode. If I change it to `default` mode, my VS Code starts to lag and freeze like crazy because the `lib` folder takes up most of the memory usage due to its large code volume. How can I exclude the `lib` folder, and possibly others of my choice from the IntelliSense process?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using the `C_Cpp.files.exclude` setting. It has a similar form to the `files.exclude` setting. Its description reads:

> The glob pattern to match file paths against. Set to `true` or `false` to enable or disable the pattern.

Perhaps something like this:

```json
"C_Cpp.files.exclude": {
   "**/.vscode": true,
   "**/.vs": true,
   "lib/": true
},
```

You might also be able to use [VS Code variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) in this context, if needed.