# How to exclude certain directories from VS Code CPPtools

Tags: visual-studio-code

Got a question - I've got two SDKs directories within my project's folder on remote host. Those SDKs contain tons of files and VSCode is trying to index them which causes CPPtools process to consume all of available RAM on my VM and I have to kill them once they render my environment unusable. Is there a way to exclude those SDKs in the same manner as in git.ignore?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76419852/vs-code-c-intellisense-exclude-files/76420253#76420253